# The Game of Nim

Tags: puzzle, recreational-mathematics

A position in Nim consists of some piles of coins. Two players alternate, with each move removing a portion of one pile. The winner is the player who takes the last coin.

Suppose that the starting piles have size $n_1,...,n_k$. Prove that Player 2 has a winning startegy if and only if for every $j$, an even number of $n_1,...,n_k$ have a $1$ in position $j$ in their binary representation. For example, when the sizes are $1,2,3$, the binary representation are $1, 10, 11,$ and the condition holds.

Comment: Have you even read the Wikipedia article on [Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim)?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a well known result. Surely you can google up something, or failing that, go to a math library and read a solution from "Winning Ways I-II" by Berlekamp, Conway and Guy.

But I'm glad to hear that you want to work it out yourself. Here are a couple of hints. Call a position in the game of Nim *balanced*, if the sequence of numbers of remaining coins in the piles satisfies the condition "even number of 1s in any position", and call it *unbalanced* otherwise.

1) Show that if a player is given a balanced position, then any move s/he will make leaves an unbalanced position.

2) Show that if we are given an unbalanced position, there exists a move (at least one, possibly more) that will leave the other player with a balanced position.

3) Note that the desired all-zeros end position is balanced. Apply a little bit of recursive thinking (or induction, if you like).

Comment: "glad to hear..." -? It sounds like he wants **us** to work it out!

Comment: @The Chaz: Given that the OP didn't just use a Wikipedia article or some such, my inner optimist wants to hang on to a positive world view. The role of the teacher is to inspire! </tongue-in-cheek>

Comment: My browser didn't complie the tongue in cheek! Regardless, I appreciate your optimism

Comment: Sorry if it came off as me asking for the answer. It sort of was. I was stuck on a problem and you pointed me in the right direction, I'm thankful for that.